# regex int or float

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My regex won't work on single digit number

```
/^[0-9]{1,7}\.?[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

I need it to work on unsigned numbers:

```
1 (single digit numbers, without fractions) - currently it fails on them
1.0; 0.31 (floating point numbers)
```

Number before fraction can be 1-7 digits; after fraction 1-2 digits.

Thanks you!

Comment: "unsigned" and "floating point" are internal to the machine, and have nothing to do with their human readable representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're specifying that there must be 1-7 digits, then an optional decimal point, then 1-2 more digits. Try:

```
/^[0-9]{1,7}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Note that this doesn't allow trailing decimal places (i.e. "1."). If you want to allow that, this should work:

```
/^[0-9]{1,7}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/
```

Comment: At the same time, the second expression allows numbers with 8-9 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Make the decimal point and the digits after it optional. e.g.

```
/^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

That way you can have a either 1 - 7 digits *or* 1 - 7 digits followed by a decimal point followed by 1 or 2 digits *but* if you had digits followed by a decimal point but no further digits that would not be valid.